# Yii2 subquery in Active Record

Tags: yii, yii2

How can I convert this sql into active record query

```
SELECT * FROM `base_twitter` WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT base_id from base_followers)
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Assuming that your models are named `BaseTwitter` and `BaseFollower` accordingly, this should work:

```
$subQuery = BaseFollower::find()->select('id');
$query = BaseTwitter::find()->where(['not in', 'id', $subQuery]);
$models = $query->all();
```

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes

Comment: Is this possible for more than one column? I mean can I select more than one column in the subquery and then use them in $query?

Answer (score 13):

```
// SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `active` = 1) `activeusers`;
$subquery = (new \yii\db\Query)->from('user')->where(['active' => true])
$query = (new \yii\db\Query)->from(['activeusers' => $subquery]);

// subquery can also be a string with plain SQL wrapped in parenthesis
// SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `active` = 1) `activeusers`;
$subquery = "(SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `active` = 1)";
$query = (new \yii\db\Query)->from(['activeusers' => $subquery]);
```

Comment: This is not active record. The output will be array

Answer (score 3):

Try This Query

```
$models = BaseTwitter::find()->where('id NOT IN (SELECT base_id from base_followers)')->all();
```