# Complex subqueries in yii2

Tags: activerecord, subquery, yii2

can anyone frame this sub query in yii2???

```
select name, crt_by, (select name from tbl_employee_master 
                       where tbl_employee_master.contact = (select username from tbl_user 
                       where tbl_user.id = tbl_dealer_master.crt_by)) as 
                       employee, district, contact_person, contact,
 (select count(*) from tbl_dealer_post 
  where tbl_dealer_post.fk_user_id = tbl_dealer_master.id) 
  as post_count from tbl_dealer_master 
  where status=1
```

Help is appreciable!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you want answer with `activerecord` or `activequery`?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record

Answer (score 4):

Here is `activequery` you can use ..

```
$query= (new Query())->select([
        'name' ,
        'crt_by' ,
        'employee' => (new Query())->select('name')
            ->from('tbl_employee_master')
            ->where([
                '=','tbl_employee_master.contact', (new Query())
                    ->select('username')
                    ->from('tbl_user')
                    ->where('tbl_user.id=tbl_dealer_master.crt_by')
            ]),
        'district',
        'contact_person',
        'contact',
        'post_count' => (new Query())->select('count(*)')
            ->from('tbl_dealer_post')
            ->where('tbl_dealer_post.fk_user_id=tbl_dealer_master.id')
    ])->from('tbl_dealer_master')->where(['status' => 1]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt reply!! I guess you missed the from clause in the parent query section!!

Comment: Ohh ya... thanks for remind me...I have updated it.. Please Upvote if answer is valid for future users prospective .....

Answer (score -3):

This is the complete solution to the given problem!!

```
$query= (new Query())->select([
        'name' ,
        'crt_by' ,
        'employee' => (new Query())->select('name')
            ->from('tbl_employee_master')
            ->where([
                '=','tbl_employee_master.contact', (new Query())
                    ->select('username')
                    ->from('tbl_user')
                    ->where('tbl_user.id=tbl_dealer_master.crt_by')
            ]),
        'district',
        'contact_person',
        'contact',
        'post_count' => (new Query())->select('count(*)')
            ->from('tbl_dealer_post')
            ->where('tbl_dealer_post.fk_user_id=tbl_dealer_master.id')
    ])->from('tbl_dealer_master')->where(['status' => 1]);
```