# Yii2: How to convert query with subquery to Actived Record?

Tags: sql, postgresql, yii2, rails-activerecord, yii2-advanced-app

I want to convert this very simple SQL query with a subquery to **Yii Active Record** (I am using PostgreSQL).

```
SELECT
  totals.name,
  FROM (
    SELECT
      products.id,
      products.name
    FROM "products"
  ) AS totals
```

How can I convert it to Active Record?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record) but it's not exactly what I need.

Comment: it there a group in that query? because it looks like you're just doing  `SELECT products.name FROM products`

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can use findBySql() ActiveRecord static method.

```
$subquery = (new \yii\db\Query)->from('products')->select(['id','name']);
$query = (new \yii\db\Query)->from(['totals' => $subquery])->select('name');

$items = Model::findBySql($query->createCommand()->getRawSql())->all();
```