# How to pass subquery as table name to another query in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I have a query which I am trying to convert into yii2 syntax. Below is the query

```
 SELECT project_id, user_ref_id FROM 
            (
            SELECT `project_id`, `user_ref_id`
            FROM `projectsList` 
            WHERE user_type_ref_id = 1) AS a WHERE user_ref_id = '.yii::$app->user->id;
```

I am trying to convert it into yii2 format like

```
 $subQuery = (new Query())->select(['p.project_id', 'p.user_ref_id'])->from('projectsList')->where(['user_type_ref_id' => 1]);

 $uQuery = (new Query())->select(['p.project_id', 'p.user_ref_id'])->from($subQuery)->where(['user_ref_id ' => yii::$app->user->id])->all();
```

It is giving an error like

```
 trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

How to I pass subquery as table name to another query

Comment: Double of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record

Comment: but I don't understend why not ```SELECT project_id, user_ref_id FROM projectsList  WHERE user_type_ref_id = 1 AND user_ref_id = yii::$app->user->id```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 subquery in Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but generally this is how it goes. You need to pass the subQuery as a table. So change `->from($subQuery)` in the second query to `->from(['subQuery' => $subQuery])`

```
$subQuery = (new Query())->select(['p.project_id', 'p.user_ref_id'])->from('projectsList')->where(['user_type_ref_id' => 1]);
```

Then

```
 $query = (new Query())->select(['p.project_id', 'p.user_ref_id'])->from(['subQuery' => $subQuery])->where(['subQuery.user_ref_id ' => yii::$app->user->id])->all();
```