# how to use subquery inside select statement of yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I have a query as below.

```
 $subQuery = (new Query())->select('is_approved')->from('user_requests')->where(['user_ref_id' => yii::$app->user->id])->andWhere(['AND','project_ref_id = p.project_id']);
```

This is the subquery which I am trying to call in select statement as below

```
 $Query = (new Query())->select(['project_id','IF(p.project_type_ref_id = 2, '.$subQuery.', "" ) AS project_request_id'])
                             ->from('projects AS p');
```

If I try to execute the query I am getting below error in the line where I added $subQuery

```
PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Object of class yii\db\Query could not be converted to string
```

How to add a subquery in select statement. Please help. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass subquery as table name to another query in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48680018/how-to-pass-subquery-as-table-name-to-another-query-in-yii2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 subquery in Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use first query as pure string add

```
->createCommand()->rawSql;
```

to it. This generates SQL statement out of Query object.