# yii2-Active record with not in condition

Tags: activerecord, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, notin

I am working on `yii2`. I am using active record for searching a reference number. The query is below

```
$q = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '';
    if(empty($q)) exit;
    $ser = Survey::find()->where("ref_no like '%$q%'")->andWhere(['status'=>1])->asArray()->all();

    return json_encode($ser);
```

The above query will get all the reference numbers which are in survey table. Now I want to add a `NOT IN` condition. The raw query is below

`...... where ref_no LIKE '%$q%' NOT IN (select ref_no from installations where ref_no LIKE '%q%')`

How can I add this to my active record query?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 subquery in Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your Query as Below :

```
$ser = Survey::find()->where("ref_no like '%$q%'")
->andWhere(['status'=>1])
->andWhere("ref_no NOT IN (select ref_no from installations where ref_no LIKE '%q%')")
->asArray()->all();
```

OR

```
$ser = Survey::find()
->where("ref_no like '%$q%' AND ref_no NOT IN (select ref_no from installations where ref_no LIKE '%q%')")
->andWhere(['status'=>1])
->asArray()->all();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery for this too (assuming your installation table i related  to Installations model)

```
  $subQuery = Installations::find()->select('ref_no')->where("ref_no like '%$q%'");
  $query = Survey::find()->where(['not in', 'ref_no', $subQuery]);
  $models = $query->all();
```

Comment: this is a neater approach `+1` as i also use the same **(⌐■_■)**

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam  ... thanks.  is the approach based on yii2 "guidelines"