# How to do Subquery for same Table in Yii2 Eloquent

Tags: yii

how to create this query using model in **yii2**

```
select *,p1.plan_id from product p1 
    where id in (select max(p2.id) from product p2 where p2.plan_id = p1.plan_id)
```

form the following table **Product**

```
id   product_name  plan_id
-------------------------------
1    bottle          1
2    book            2
3    book            2
4    bottle          1
5    notbook         3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 subquery in Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record)

Comment: In This link subquery has not where conditions

Comment: There is no such thing as `Yii2 Eloquent`. You want to use `ActiveRecord` or just create query using query builder?

Comment: @ShringirajDewangan change the first argument to `in`

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor you query using an inner join eg:

```
 $sql = "select *
    from product p1 
    inner join (
      select plan_id, max(id) max_id 
      from product 
      group by plain_id
    ) t on t.plan_id = p1.plan_id and p1.id = t.max_id";
```

and in some case could be useful findBySql, assuming your model is name Product

```
$models = Product::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

This ***should*** be the exact query you *would do*, **but** [it won't work for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892762/mysql-this-version-of-mysql-doesnt-yet-support-limit-in-all-any-some-subqu):

```
// select *, p1.plan_id from product p1
//     where id in (select max(p2.id) from product p2 where p2.plan_id = p1.plan_id)

$subquery = (new \yii\db\Query)->select('[[p2]].[[id]]')
    ->from(['p2' => 'product'])
    ->where('[[p2]].[[plan_id]] = [[p1]].[[plan_id]]')
    ->orderBy('[[p2]].[[id]] DESC')->limit(1); // equiv to max(p2.id)

$query = (new \yii\db\Query)->from(['p1' => 'product'])
    ->where(['p1.id' => $subquery])
    ->one();

// PS: Yii will quote fields wrapped in `[[]]` double square-brackets.
```

### Using `join`s

So, you should use `innerJoin` (or other variants) to achieve the same result working for any database:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query)->from(['p1' => 'product'])
    ->innerJoin(['product p2'], '[[p2]].[[plan_id]] = [[p1]].[[plan_id]]')
    ->orderBy('[[p2]].[[id]] DESC')->limit(1); // equiv to max(p2.id)
    ->one();
```