# Yii2: how to use subquery with ActiveRecord?

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, yii2, subquery

I want to create a find function to use then in a GridView widget My I don't know how to use a subquery.

This is the simple version of the PostgreSQL query that I have:

```
SELECT color
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name
    FROM companies
)
```

Here is what I a trying and doesn't work:

```
$query = Cars::find()
    ->select([
        'color' => '
            SELECT name     // Problem here.
            FROM companies  // Problem here.
        ',
    ]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yii2 subquery in Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164491/yii2-subquery-in-active-record)

Comment: What is the purpose? Can you split it in two queries?

Answer (score 2):

Your expected query is not what you are trying to do. You can add a custom subquery as

```
$query = Cars::find()
    ->select([
       '(SELECT name FROM companies) AS xxx'
    ]);
```

But if you want to add a field from joined table to the grid, then you should have  a relation defined and then you can easily add such a column to your grid. See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use instance of `ActiveQuery` in `leftJoin()` method like this:

```php
$subQuery = Companies::find()
    ->select('name', 'id'); //I've added ID to show how to write on condition
$query = Cars::find()
    ->select('color')
    ->leftJoin(
        ['alias' => $subQuery],
        'alias.id = cars.company_id'
    );
```

See [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#leftJoin()-detail) for more details about `leftJoin()` and `join()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = Cars::find()
    ->select(['cars.color','companies.name'])
    ->leftJoin('companies', 'cars.company_id = companies.id');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.